# Rendering vanishing text in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a small game using pygame. When the game starts I want to display "start" and vanish it after a few seconds. How to do that?

Comment: Do you mean the text should slowly become more transparent or should it suddenly disappear?

Comment: I prefer both. suddenly disappear is just enough

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467863/how-to-remove-replace-text-in-pygame/30347108#30347108) might help.

Answer (score 4):

First you need a timer variable (there are other questions about timers, so I won't explain them here). I'm just counting the frames in the following example.

To remove the text abruptly you can just keep blitting it until the time is up.

```
if timer > 0: 
    screen.blit(txt_surf, (position))
```

---

The slowly disappearing text can be achieved by filling the text surface with white and the current alpha value (which is reduced each frame) and by passing the `pg.BLEND_RGBA_MULT` special flag. That will affect only the alpha channel of the surface.

```
txt_surf.fill((255, 255, 255, alpha), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
```

Also, use a copy of the original text surface, otherwise it would subsequently reduce the alpha of the previously modified surface and the text would disappear too quickly.

```
import pygame as pg


def main():
    pg.init()
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 64)
    orig_surf = font.render('Enter your text', True, pg.Color('royalblue'))
    txt_surf = orig_surf.copy()
    alpha = 255  # The current alpha value of the surface.
    timer = 20  # To get a 20 frame delay.

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                return

        if timer > 0:
            timer -= 1
        else:
            if alpha > 0:
                # Reduce alpha each frame, but make sure it doesn't get below 0.
                alpha = max(0, alpha-4)
                # Create a copy so that the original surface doesn't get modified.                
                txt_surf = orig_surf.copy()
                txt_surf.fill((255, 255, 255, alpha), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        screen.blit(txt_surf, (30, 60))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding below code:

```
for i in range(whatevernumberbutnotover1000):
    mytext.set_alpha(i)
```